# How to pinch zoom Android emulator embedded in Android Studio IDE (2020)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, pinchzoom

It seems to work by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and left mouse in normal emulator but since Android 4.1.1, the emulator can be embedded into the IDE, I could not perform pinch zoom.

Any help! Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but if you opt to not Launch in a Tool Window under Preferences -> Emulator -> uncheck the box, you can still pinch zoom by using the ctrl button.  Looks like pinch zoom does not work when emulator is embedded in a tool window.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mac, Control + trackpad will do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try,(make sure you are on emulator)

Press F1 (or 3 menu dots at the side of emulator from where you can rotate emulators) -> Settings -> Send Keyboard shortcuts to -> Emulator Controls